# Error creating Java Date in php

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

Im trying to create a php function that converts a string date to a java date to pass to java. I need to use java.sql.Date not java.util.Date for my application. But this simple function is giving an odd result:

```
function makeStrJavaDate($date){
    $date = date_parse($date);
    $date = new Java("java.sql.Date",$date['year'], $date['month']-1, $date['day']);
    return $date;
}
```

The date java returned has the wrong year: php (For 2011-07-01), java(Jul 1, 3911).

Any pointers as to whats wrong?

FYI, php is parsing it correctly:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2011
    [month] => 7
    [day] => 1
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Comment: Please `print_r($date)` after the `date_parse` and before the `new Java` and show us the output.

Comment: Just a thought, isn't the java timestamp a millisecond version of the unix time stamp?  So if you get the timestamp in php, add 000 to the end, and send it to java.  Or vis-versa, divide by a 1000 in php once you receive it from the java program.  I'm not sure if that will work though, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, it's considering the year to start at 1900.  So subtract 1900 when you pass the year.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bizarro variant of Y2K (you're off by 1900 years). You can fix this by subtracting 1900 years from `$date['year']`, but I'm wondering if you wouldn't be better off using `strtotime` and just passing in a timestamp, especially since `Date(int year, int month, int day)` is [deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29).